# Connect to Microsoft Access Database from XCode

Tags: database, macos, ms-access, odbc, database-connection

I've been tasked with writing a Mac App in xcode 4.3 that can search and display data from a publicly available MS Access Database that's updated regularly.  For this reason, I can't just convert the file to a different database platform.  I've searched the depths of Google and can't find anyone else attempting such a task.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 'the depths of google' now end on this page :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use 3rd party tools that provide connectivity like actualtech one.
http://www.actualtech.com/product_access.php
I personally never tried this one, but it looks promising.

I believe there are no native Microsoft support for other platforms than Windows.

Comment: Thanks Maksym,  I've actually already been talking with the developers at Actual Technologies.  They are working on a new version of their Access driver that I can use in X-Code.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: I just want to point out that this Actual ODBC Driver for Access Databases is a commercial solution. I haven't come across a free/open source solution that's better suited for non-profit or educational use.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is in an MDB file, you could try using this online [MDB to MySQL converter](http://www.mdb2mysql.com/).

You could write a daemon that fetches the latest SQL dump daily or even hourly and stores it in a local SQLite file. Then your client app just needs to query the local file.

I know it's not as convenient as connecting to the database directly, but this is a 'free' solution.